# Is there a function that can access a timer's functionalities (i.e. start and end the timer) in C++?

Tags: c++, time

I am a C++ beginner and I have been working on a C++ question where I hope to look at how my algorithm is working. I want to be able to start and end a timer anywhere in the main method in a short and simple way if I wished (so that it doesn't really influence my function's CPU during timing). I hope to *directly* get the time in milliseconds. I know that in Python the `time` library can solve the problem directly (by using the method in Appendix A), but I wonder if there is in C++. Is there a short and convenient method of doing that? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.
(1) My current C++ code is just translating Appendix A to C++.
(2) I learned C++ by myself, so I haven't really seen many books about C++ programming yet. Thus, recommending internet resources about the library is great help for me such that I can use it in future programming.

**Appendix A: Code snippet**

Appendix A content (mentioned above) is shown as follows:

```py
def func(): # Do something
import time
start = time.time()
func()
end = time.time()
print(f"Process completed in {end - start} milliseconds.")
```

Comment: I wish to know about all the functionalities of the library too! Thank you!

Comment: There is STL's chrono library. Just checkout cpp reference.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chrono-in-c/amp/ have a look at this, it has a simple example to do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check chrono library, type on YouTube "The cherno Timing in C++" à very useful video for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you! I checked out these videos and they are extremely good!